How to recover automatically a failed primary node as standby node in Pgpool?
Imagine there is two node (primary and standby node) which they are already configured failover.
If primary node is down, standby node can promote as primary node
But in this case, I want to also design that if the failed node is recovered, he turns as a standby node.
I'm searching some documents in pgpool officiel site (https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-online-recovery.html) but I'm not sure how exactly configure for that
Can you guys help me with details??

follow_primary_command (string) in 5.10. failerover and failback:
"   for each backend node
{
if (the node is not the new primary)
set down node status to shared memory status
memorize that follow primary command is needed to execute
}
if (we need to executed follow primary command)
{
fork a child process
(within the child process)
    for each backend node
    {
        if (the node status in shared memory is down)
            execute follow primary command
    }
}


https://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/en/html/runtime-config-failover.html
